# LoadingCache with Closeable

Tags: dispose

How do I dispose of Closeable objects when using a LoadingCache?

Do I need to save off a reference to what I have in the `build` call, and close it before creating a new one?

```
private final LoadingCache<String, BigtableDataClient> DATA_CLIENT_LOADING_CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(50, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, BigtableDataClient>() {
                @Override
                public BigtableDataClient load(final String key) {
... // in here?
                }
```